# How to solve common log problem given the following with the help of calculator?

Tags: logarithms

the question is 
$$\log_{10}(x + 8) + 6 = 8$$

$$\log_{10}(x+8) = 2$$

$$10^2 = x + 8 $$

I just turned it into exponential form.
Now my question is if i did this right at all? and if i did how would i go on solving it?

Comment: Assuming the logarithms are base $10$, yes, so that $x = 10^2 - 8 = 92$

Comment: yes its is base 10, how would i solve after this?

Comment: You've already solved it, just rearrange for $x$. The answer is $x=10^2-8=92$.

Comment: ohh ok i see now thanks

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind, how would i solve $$10^(3x+2) = 29$$

Comment: @MATH ASKER It seems strange to me that you can manipulate logs, yet you struggle with what is generally considered an elementary equation to solve, the linear equation in your comment. Could you explain where you are having trouble?

Comment: Just multiply a number $n$ to whatever is enclosed in the parentheses:

$$n(a+b) = x$$
$$(na + nb) = x$$

In your case you'd have:

$$10(3x+2) = 29$$
$$30x + 20 = 29$$

Then solve for $x$.

Alternatively you could have:

$$\left(\frac{10}{10}\right)(3x + 2) = (29)\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)$$
$$3x + 2 = \frac{29}{10}$$

Then solve for $x$.

But as @Cataline mentioned, how can you manipulate logs but struggle with very elementary algebra?

Comment: @Cataline if you look at the markup for the second equation it's a typo for $10^{3x+2}=29$

Comment: @Aldon it was undoubtedly a markup error

Answer (score 0):

In solving equations involving exponentials and logarithms it's important to remember they are inverse operations of each other, so exponentiating both sides we get

$$\begin{align}\log_a x &= c \\ \Rightarrow a^{\log_a x} &= a^c \\ \Rightarrow x &= a^c\end{align}$$

or taking the logarithm of both sides we get

$$\begin{align}a^x &= c \\ \Rightarrow \log_a(a^x) &= \log_a c \\ \Rightarrow x\log_a(a) &= \log_a c \\ \Rightarrow x &= \log_a c\end{align}$$
by the laws of logarithms.